# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/TableGenerators

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

Im trying to develop a BackEnd app using hibernate JPA into Tomcat.
From now it was working fine at test with JPA functionality and a 1st version without the JPA's services is working right now (file uploads, downloads and this stuff).

Now I'm in my way to integrate the JPA to apply all the functions we need but, even when all test work fine (including service tests), im getting the following 500 error when I submit the request from Postman to the local server.

This is the exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/TableGenerators
```

This is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.itvcvr</groupId>
  <artifactId>RESTfullApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>RESTfullApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.30</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.29</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.inject</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.29</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.inject</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.29</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.inject</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.29.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.29.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomee/javaee-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>RESTfullApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And the exception triggers during the generation of the Entity Manager

```
em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testDb").createEntityManager();
```

JDBC driver is also registred before the instance of the eEntity Manager

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm also using the pluging enforce to check if any dependency is creating any version incompatibility in my pom.xml.

This is the first project i have to configure from 0 and this question is my last resource to solve the problem i have.

Thanks you all :D

Answer (score 2):

In most situations, this error says that the classloader cannot find the class your code depends on.

In your case the class named javax/persistence/TableGenerators expected to be on the classpath, but for some reasons it's not.

The TableGenerators class is packaged within *javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar* file.

Before deploying your *.war* file on tomacat, check whether the requierd jars on the classpath - enter into your RESTfullApp.war file and look at the WEB-INF/lib folder, the javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar must be there, otherwise fix your maven build in order to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

It also worth to mention, that exploded .war folder in Tomcat ($CATALINA_BASE/webapps/RESTfullApp) must have the same layout and contain the same set of files you see in 
 your .war archive, check the javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar is also there.

In case the mentioned .jar are present on the classpath, I would also suggest you checking the javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar is not broken.

Sometimes, it happens to be maven downloads broken .jar archives which might cause the error you see.
At least, you can try to unzip this jar file and check if there will be any errors while extracting this jar.

Comment: For now, when I export the project into the .war file, it contains the javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar. I'm not actually trying to execute it on the server but in local. Can it be an issue between Tomcat 9.0 and Windows? Unfortunately, I cannot switch my OS to an unix distribution yet. I add once more the specific library in my pom.xml but still not working in local. Same error.

Comment: @KevinLopez Are you trying to run your application from Eclispe or some other IDE?

Comment: I'm running it from Eclipse. I lazily tried to import the projecto into InteliJ Idea but I got some library issues so I couldn't try to run int from that ide. Some ideas?

Comment: .jar file seems to be correct. After unpacking the javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar I'd check if TableGenerator.class is inside and it is. I will try to test the .war file into a virtual machine with a properly installed tomcat (like what I have in the live server) and test if it works.

Comment: it also might be a file permissions issue, check your tomcat instance run under user who has read/execute access to the javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Bad news... The current config I'd display works properly in the server. That probably means the problem I'm getting is from a problem between Tomcatn and Windows. For now the test are returning a 404 code (the catch exit of the code) but now all is about working in the service and make some tests before publishing the service. Any way, thanks for the help.